Argo CD Image Updater certificate signed by unknown authority problem
I have a docker registry which using self signed certificate. When i tried to use on Argo Cd Image Updater i faced the following error
FATA[0000] could not get tags: Get "https://192.168.100.25:5000/v2/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority  application=test image_alias= image_digest= image_name="192.168.100.25:5000/alpine" image_tag=latest registry_url="192.168.100.25:5000"
My registry conf;
> data:
> registries.conf: |
> registries:
> name: my-registry
> api_url: https://192.168.100.25:5000
> insecure: true
> prefix: 192.168.100.25:5000

As far as I see in the documentation setting insecure=true bypasses the tls verification, even though I set it, I still facing the same error. Any suggestions? Thanks
